# zIndex -1 on button is making button unclickable

Tags: css, reactjs, button, material-ui, z-index

I want to make the button clickable.

[image]

Here is the sandbox. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/m5w3y76mvy

Comment: Instead of linking to an external site, create a [minimal, concrete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself. Meanwhile, using a `zIndex` of `-1` will surely make your button unclickable. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: increase the z-index of the circle instead of decrease the one of the button

Comment: Is it possible to overwrite style for .ContainedButtons-numberCircle-458 class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For numberCircle added 
 `position: relative;
 z-index: 1;`

and set mytasks z-index as 0 `zIndex: "0"` I think it will works.

Check the overall style

```
    mytasks: {
    color: "white",
    borderColor: "#2D9CDB",
    backgroundColor: "#2D9CDB",
    borderTopRightRadius: "18px",
    borderBottomRightRadius: "18px",
    borderTopLeftRadius: "18px",
    borderBottomLeftRadius: "18px",
    width: "200px",
    marginLeft: "-35px",
    zIndex: "0" /* changed to 0 */
  },
  numberCircle: {
    borderRadius: "50%",
    behavior: "url(PIE.htc)" /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */,
    width: "15px",
    height: "15px",
    padding: "8px",
    background: "white",
    border: "2px solid #2D9CDB",
    color: "#2D9CDB",
    textAlign: "center",
    font: "16px Arial, sans-serif",
    float: "left",
    zIndex: "1",/* added */
    position: "relative"/* added */
  }
```